# How does React differentiate between two useEffect hooks with a dependency array with the same length?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

How does React differentiate between two useEffect hooks with a dependency array with the same length? Can it even do that?

I have a code similar to this one below.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('age changed')
}, [age])

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('name changed')
}, [name])
```

At first it seemed that React would be checking if the variable with the name `age` or `name` had changed, but then I quickly realized that once the value is evaluated, it'd simply became an array like `[5]` or `["Chris"]`, but it'd wouldn't be able to tell which hook to execute.

However my test shows that the correct hook is chosen.

Is this because of some lucky bug in my code that makes it happen the way I expected (but shouldn't be)? Or does React have some magic to tell which variable was updated even though what's being passed is just the value?

I researched a lot, but it seems nobody has this specific doubt about hooks.

Comment: That's why you can't change the _order_ of hooks, e.g. by calling them conditionally: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-does-react-associate-hook-calls-with-components, https://overreacted.io/why-do-hooks-rely-on-call-order/, ...

Comment: @jonrsharpe How does that relate to my question? Edit: Thanks, I'll read the links (seems to be related)

Comment: `[5] or ["Chris"]`, but this will get updated on the next render, so if age had changed to 6, it would be `[6], ["Chris"]`..  So yes, it's not checking to see if a var has changed, it's checking to see if evaluation is different.  Put it another way, you could have `[Math.random()]`, that would practically be a no-op dependency.

Comment: To clarify, the dependency doesn't cause a re-render, you will still need to mix this with some external state like `setState()` etc for the effect to re-run.

Comment: "The dependency array can contain multiple dependencies. React will only skip re-running the Effect if all of the dependencies you specify have exactly the same values as they had during the previous render. **React compares the dependency values using the Object.is comparison.**"